# Bootstrap: Radio button value is not submitted if checked twice

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my form I have a group of radio buttons:

```
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-danger">
        <input name="Status" type="radio" value="2">Failed</label>
    <label class="btn btn-warning">
        <input name="Status" type="radio" value="0">Pending</label>
    <label class="btn btn-success active">
        <input name="Status" type="radio" value="1">Success</label>
 </div>
```

When I select one radio option and submit the form everything works as expected, but if I double click on an option, that option gets broken and is not sent with a form submit unless I check another option.

Looks like `data-toggle="buttons"` attribute causes the issue.

Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9K8L/)

Comment: `twitter-bootstrap` and `twitter-bootstrap-3` have been established as the proper tags for the Bootstrap front-end framework.

Comment: Since you continue to add in your incorrect tag, I am locking this. *Please do not continue to do this after the lock has expired.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found that it's a known bug: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9920

Answer (score 1):

I saw this solution in the Github issue page. and this worked for me.

temporary solution:

```
    $("input[type=radio][name=gender]").on("change", function(){
         $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known bug in v3.0 and will be fixed in the next release

[Radio checked property is removed on second click with data-toggle="buttons](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9920)

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and found that it was a bug, but it's resolved now. Reference https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9920

Resolved issue in v3.0.2, please figure if it's nightly build or released officially [Github].
Instead of using bootstrap.min.js, you can use a particular bootstrap js file for buttons.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/5d6e9212a642430719702ead322103e19c6aa782/js/button.js

Try having bootstrap.button.js, contents of file goes as:

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: button.js v3.0.2
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) { "use strict";

  // BUTTON PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  // ==============================

  var Button = function (element, options) {
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.options  = $.extend({}, Button.DEFAULTS, options)
  }

  Button.DEFAULTS = {
    loadingText: 'loading...'
  }

  Button.prototype.setState = function (state) {
    var d    = 'disabled'
    var $el  = this.$element
    var val  = $el.is('input') ? 'val' : 'html'
    var data = $el.data()

    state = state + 'Text'

    if (!data.resetText) $el.data('resetText', $el[val]())

    $el[val](data[state] || this.options[state])

    // push to event loop to allow forms to submit
    setTimeout(function () {
      state == 'loadingText' ?
        $el.addClass(d).attr(d, d) :
        $el.removeClass(d).removeAttr(d);
    }, 0)
  }

  Button.prototype.toggle = function () {
    var $parent = this.$element.closest('[data-toggle="buttons"]')
    var changed = true

    if ($parent.length) {
      var $input = this.$element.find('input')
      if ($input.prop('type') === 'radio') {
        // see if clicking on current one
        if ($input.prop('checked') && this.$element.hasClass('active'))
          changed = false
        else
          $parent.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      }
      if (changed) $input.prop('checked', !this.$element.hasClass('active')).trigger('change')
    }

    if (changed) this.$element.toggleClass('active')
  }


  // BUTTON PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ========================

  var old = $.fn.button

  $.fn.button = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.button')
      var options = typeof option == 'object' && option

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.button', (data = new Button(this, options)))

      if (option == 'toggle') data.toggle()
      else if (option) data.setState(option)
    })
  }

  $.fn.button.Constructor = Button


  // BUTTON NO CONFLICT
  // ==================

  $.fn.button.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.button = old
    return this
  }


  // BUTTON DATA-API
  // ===============

  $(document).on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^=button]', function (e) {
    var $btn = $(e.target)
    if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
    $btn.button('toggle')
    e.preventDefault()
  })

}(jQuery);
```

See your updated fiddle, i have added this code in `script` tags.

### See **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/Q9K8L/1/)**

Comment: Yeah! that's why I said that this bug is not there in the latest version. But this has been resolved in their master branch on github. Meanwhile for our convenience, we can use it because the later version would incorporate this issue(being fixed). The code snippet is originally from twitter itself. Nightly builds are never directly patched into the versions before upgrading them and pointing the new features. Hope you got my point. See this http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/Q9K8L/1/

Comment: If you like you can tweak your older bootstrap.min.js according to it which will resolve the issue :)