# Bootstrap 3 radio buttons not returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im struggling with Twitter Bootstrap 3 radio buttons, I am not able to get the value of checked/selected elements. I new to Jquery, but I have come accross many posts on this site how to handle radio buttons and none seems to work with Bootstrap.

HTML

```
  <form id="FormFilters" >

 // First Group of Radio
<div id="Edu" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

<label class="btn btn-block btn-info-outline" >College <input  id="Col" name="Edu" type="radio" value="Col"  ></label>
<label class="btn btn-block btn-info-outline" >High School <input  id="Sch" name="Edu" type="radio" value="School"  ></label>

</div>

// Second Group 
<div id="Experience" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

 <label class="btn btn-block btn-info-outline" >Yes <input  id="Yes" name="Exp" type="radio" value="Yes"  ></label>
<label class="btn btn-block btn-info-outline" > No <input  id="No" name="Exp" type="radio" value="No"  ></label>

</div>
</form>

 ect.../// up to 4 groups of radio btns
```

I tried :

`onclick:Javascript:alert(this.value)` 
even clicking on any element above does not return anything

`var x = $("#FormFilters input[type='radio']:checked").val();
   alert(x);` Does not return anything

`var x = $('input[type=radio]:checked', '#Edu').val(); alert(x);`

Can the styling be the issue? the `<label>` tags or class ?

Can someone tell how would you properly go through the form checked inputs / active and get the values ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's forget all of the frameworks for a moment and get back to basic Javascript.  Given some radio buttons, say:

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red"/> Red
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"/> Blue
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green"/> Green
<input type="radio" name="color" value ="white"/> White
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="shape" value="cirlce"/> Circle
<input type="radio" name="shape" value="square"/> Square
```

You could output the value of the clicked radio buttons using vanilla Javascript using:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

//attach a function
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
    //only attach the function for type radio
    if(radios[i].type == "radio"){
       radios[i].onclick = function(){
           alert(getCheckedValues());
       }
    }
}

function getCheckedValues(){
    //muste be stored in an array
    var values = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < radios.length; x++){
        if(radios[x].type == "radio" && radios[x].checked){
           values.push(radios[x].value);
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LDEJ2/

There are some very basic concepts at work in this code.  The first is selecting the elements from the `DOM`, which I have done using `document.getElementsByTagName` to retrieve all inputs.  The second concept is looping.  So now that I have selected all inputs from the DOM, I need to iterate over each one and attach an `eventhandler`.  The eventhandler is executed when some event is fired on the specific `DOM` elements.  In this case when the `click` event is fired on any radio button, I execute another function.

This function loops through the radio buttons and stores the value of all checked radio buttons in an array, which is then alerted.

Comment: Hi kevin, Thanks for posting a proper way getting value. I will use this method, However, this does not solve the problem, as I am quite sure now the issue lies in the styling, which I find weird, I removed the stylesheet, and your method above works, then again with bootstrap css, it didn't

Comment: @user3003977 That is interesting, I wonder if the CSS is hiding/replacing the radios for you.

Comment: @user3003977 The comments in the markup aka `//` are they in the actual markup?

Comment: thats what I was thinking... Thanks alot Kevin for the explanation

Comment: @user3003977 Here is a fiddle demonstrating my code + your markup + bootstrap css: http://jsfiddle.net/LDEJ2/1/

Comment: no they aren't.. I wish I could post a live demo, I am using an admin template called se7en, page table filters.. Im not sure if you have accross it..

Comment: http://sharpandnimble.com/se7en/demo/filters.html
Checkbox below(colored ) changed type to radio...

Comment: The framework is definitely replacing the check boxes with spans, I see it hiding the radio and placing the span: `<label class="radio"><input type="radio" value="option2" name="optionsRadios1" checked=""><span>Past Week</span></label>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("input:radio").change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jPNTC/

Comment: This is the easiest way when you are using the label tag to form a css radio group in bootstrap. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the checked state of the input element is not changed when using bootstrap 3.  This works for me, finding the `input` element that is embedded in the active label.

`$('label.active > input', '#Edu').val();`

Answer (score 0):

did you tried getElementById? This is what i'm using fir js because most of the times i'm working with php GET

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('input[name=Edu]:checked').val();
```

Or more precisely only for this form-id:

```
$('input[name=Edu]:checked', '#FormFilters').val();
```

I've added a button to your form and created a fiddle to test for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Z6uZ/

You also might fetch **all selected checkboxes at once**:

```
$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
    // add $(this).val() with $(this).attr('name') to your array here
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Z6uZ/1/

**Maybe there is a bug .. see here:**  [Bootstrap: Radio button value is not submitted if checked twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081233/bootstrap-radio-button-value-is-not-submitted-if-checked-twice?rq=1)